# How to read output in python as program is running

Tags: python, stdout, popen

I want to listen to the output of a program written in AutoIT.
I start the program with :

```
p = Popen(shlex.split(args),stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, bufsize=1)
```

It works.
Somewhere I read that I should use -u to get around a buffering but I can't use that with the AutoIT program.
The problem is that while early on it writes a given text to stdout, I can't seem to hear it. I have to stop the program and then the following give me the output.

```
while p.poll() is None:
    p.stdout.flush()
    txt = p.stdout.read().decode('utf-8')
    if txt == 'Given text':
        break
```

How can I pick up the output as it is produced rather than after the program is stopped?

Comment: What is the output exactly?

Comment: It is what is written to the console in the AutoIT program that the python picks up in p.stdout.read but only when the program finishes and not as it is written.

Comment: I tried bufsize=0 but it had no effect